# Record Collection: "If" Statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Good morning, I am working on this problem on freecodecamp trying to learn JavaScript and I am unsure of where to go with it. I personally feel the wording is off, however I understand that I need to use "If" statements.

The problem says:

> You start with an updateRecords function that takes an object literal,
> records, containing the musical album collection, an id, a prop (like
> artist or tracks), and a value. Complete the function using the rules
> below to modify the object passed to the function.
> Your function must always return the entire record collection object.

1. **If prop isn't tracks and value isn't an empty string, update or set
   that album's prop to value.**
2. **If prop is tracks but the album doesn't have a tracks property, create an empty array and add value to it.**
3. **If prop is tracks and value isn't an empty string, add value to the end
   of the album's existing tracks array.**
4. **If value is an empty string,
   delete the given prop property from the album.**

Note: A copy of the

> recordCollection object is used for the tests.

The code I have right now

```
// Setup
var recordCollection = {
  2548: {
    albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
    artist: 'Bon Jovi',
    tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
  },
  2468: {
    albumTitle: '1999',
    artist: 'Prince',
    tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
  },
  1245: {
    artist: 'Robert Palmer',
    tracks: []
  },
  5439: {
    albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
  }
};

// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
  if (prop !== 'tracks' && (!(recordCollection[id]).tracks)) {
    recordCollection[id].tracks = [];
  } else if (prop.tracks) {
    prop.album
  }

  return records;
}

updateRecords(recordCollection, 5439, 'artist', 'ABBA');
```

Really in particular it's the bottom part that I've actually written. But I am at a loss and I am not sure how to interpret the requirements of these if statements.

I am appreciative of any kind of help that I can get on this. I don't want it to stifle me, but I am finding problem solving to be a bit of challenge for me more than I am finding Javascript syntax to be an issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have 4 very distinct requirements, all requiring an `if` statement you could start simply by coding them one at a time. You'll end up with 4 repeats of

```
if(some_condition)
{
    // perform some action
}
```

Once you've done this you'll work out that 2 can be combined because they both start with "If prop is tracks"

---

Your `prop` argument is a string, so this will always return false `else if (prop.tracks)` as `prop.tracts` is undefined which is falsey in javascript

---

You've *partially* solved point 2, emphasis mine

> If prop is tracks but the album doesn't have a tracks property, create an empty array and **add value to it.**

You missed the part in bold

---

Deleting a property in javascript can be achieved with the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

---

Adding to the end of an array can be done with the [`push` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

---

Hope this helps you along a bit. I've avoided writing you code as you said you're trying to learn!

Comment: Thanks for working with me. I have a few more questions if you don't mind... Why is prop considered a string? And does that mean that I must refer to it as 'prop'?
**what is the relevancy of: (!(recordCollection[id]).tracks) in my if statements?**
am I using that to tap in to my entire record collection?

for my first if statement I have a total of:

if (prop == 'tracks' && (!(recordCollection[id]).tracks)) {
    let tracks = []
    tracks.push('value')
    return recordCollection;

Comment: @goldwind1111 `prop` is a string because you passed a string as that argument. strings do have some [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#instance_methods) but mostly yes you will just refer to `prop` - `prop.tracks` does not make any sense. `(!(recordCollection[id]).tracks)` is checking for the inexistence of a tracks property on the element in the array (part of your requirement). Your final code in that comment looks like the correct implementation for requirement (2).

Comment: Hey thank you man! I figured it ou, but thank you so much for your help and guidance! Love.